# How many poker hands until statistically significant winner

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poker

How many poker hands do I have to play to determine a statistically significant winner? What is the best approach to get a 95% confidence interval?

To give some more context: I have been building a poker bot that plays online poker. I start with giving it 2 dollars and let it play around 500 hands. The outcome seems quite random. Sometimes it wins $3 and sometimes it loses around 1 dollar after the 500 hands. I'm wondering how many hands I have to play until I can determine on a statistically significant level if the bot it playing well enough to make money.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Right now, your question seems to be missing some context. Can you give some more details?

Comment: I have been building a poker bot that plays online poker. I start with giving it $2 and let it play around 500 hands. The outcome seems quite random. Sometimes it wins $3 and sometimes it loses around $1 after the 500 hands. I'm wondering how many hands I have to play until I can determine on a statistically significant level if the bot it playing well enough to make money.

Comment: Could you edit this into the question?: use the edit button underneath the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is impossible to answer, because it depends heavily on the general skill level. A skilful game will have a much lower variance than a beginners' game.

Comment: What would be the best way to measure all that?